# Beweis, Nachweis, Zeichen - a nominal expression expressing the same as Mut beweisen

Tags: vocabulary

I would like to express with a nominal group the same as *"Dreistigkeit beweisen"* which I think I do here with *"ein Zeichen von Dreistigkeit".* Is the following example correct?

> Es hat sich herausgestellt, dass er **dieses Zeichen von Dreistigkeit** als eine Beleidigung auffasste.

May we say

> Es hat sich herausgestellt, dass er **diesen Beweis von Dreistigkeit** als eine Beleidigung auffasste.

I understand that *"ein Nachweis von Dreistigkeit"* would not be semantically possible, *"Nachweis"* is more a scientific proof, a proof which can be endorsed by facts.

Would you say other ways of saying ?

Comment: Es hat sich herausgestellt, 
dass er diesen Beweis von Dreistigkeit 
als eine Beleidigung auffasste. to be grammaticaly correct, accusative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the words that you suggested:

> Zeichen von Dreistigkeit
> Beweis von Dreistigkeit
> Nachweis von Dreistigkeit
> Äußerung von Dreistigkeit

However, when talking about style, the verb in "Dreistigkeit beweisen" is very weak and doesn't add much meaning. Also, the noun *Dreistigkeit* isn't only used to characterize a person that is "dreist", but also acts that are "dreist". You could even say that "Dreistigkeit" is more apt to describe an action than a person's character trait, since almost nobody is "dreist" all the time.

So, "dieser Beweis von Dreistigkeit" can just be called "diese Dreistigkeit", which sounds much more succinct.

> Sein respektloses Verhalten ist eine Dreistigkeit.

> Es hat sich herausgestellt, dass er diese Dreistigkeit als eine Beleidigung auffasste.

Answer (score 0):

- zeigen, Zeichen

  > - zeigen (verb) = to show, to exhibit, to indicate, to evidence, ...
  > - das Zeichen (noun) = the sign, the indication, ...
- beweisen, Beweis

  > - beweisen (verb) = to prove, to attest, to demonstrate, to evidence, ...
  > - der Beweis (noun) = the proof, the evidence, ...
- dreist, Dreistigkeit

  > - dreist (adjective) = impudent, brazen, brash, perky, ...
  > - die Dreistigkeit (noun) = the audacidy, the presumptuousness, the brazenness, the impudentness, ...

You want to have a phrase that expresses the same as

- Dreistigkeit beweisen = to prove audacidy

So, the meaning of this phrase is *"to prove that someone is audacious"* or *"to attest that someone is impudent"* etc.

The noun, that is closest related to the verb *"beweisen"* is *"der Beweis",* so the best solution of your problem is one of these:

- nominal group with genitive attribute

  > der Beweis der Dreistigkeit
  > <sup>the proof of audacidy</sup>
- nominal group with predicative attribute

  > der Beweis von Dreistigkeit
  > <sup>the proof of audacidy</sup>
- compound noun

  > der Dreistigkeitsbeweis
  > <sup>the proof of audacidy</sup>

I would prefer the first version (*der Beweis der Dreistigkeit*), but all three are correct.

---

But the question is, if your assumption really was the best choice. I wouldn't have used *»Dreistigkeit **beweisen**«.* There are other possibilities:

1. > Er wird **Dreistigkeit beweisen.**
   > <sup>He will **prove audacidy.**</sup>
2. > Er wird **Dreistigkeit zeigen.**
   > <sup>He will **show audacidy.**</sup>
3. > Er wird **dreist sein.**
   > <sup>He will **be impudent.**</sup>

In my opinion #3 is the best choice, and #2 is the second. I would not use the verb *"beweisen"* together with *"Dreistigkeit".* You can use  *"beweisen"* together with *"Mut"* (*"Mut beweisen"* = *to show/demonstrate courage*), but *"Mut beweisen"* is what we call a *"feste Fügung"* (I don't know the exact English term for it; I think "fixed arrangement" or  "fixed phrase" describes it very well). You can't replace a part of if with another word. This will destroy the fixed arrangement, and the meaning that the fixed arrangement had, will not transfer to the new phrase.

So, you better use one of these:

1. > Anna **hat Mut bewiesen.** → Es hat sich herausgestellt, dass Bernd **diesen Mutbeweis** als eine Beleidigung auffasste.
   > <sup>Anna has shown courage. → It turned out that Bernd took this proof of courage as an insult.</sup>
2. > Anna **war dreist.** → Es hat sich herausgestellt, dass Bernd **diese Dreistigkeit** als eine Beleidigung auffasste.
   > <sup>Anna was audacious. → It turned out that Bernd took this audacity as an insult.</sup>